# Hide soft keyboard android application start up in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, phonegap-cli

I'm working on phonegap application and facing minor issue with it and tried everything but nothing works..

I've build application in android and Iphone but i'm facing issue in android only..soft keyboard is automatically showing up on start up of application.

below is my html code:-

```
<body>
<div id="page-transitions">
    <div class="header header-logo-center header-dark">
        <!-- <a href="#" class="header-icon header-icon-1 hamburger-animated open-sidebar-left"></a> -->
        <a href="index.html" class="header-logo"></a>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="header-icon header-icon-4 open-sidebar-right"><i class="ion-ios-email-outline"></i></a>     -->
    </div>

    <div id="page-content" class="page-content">
        <div id="page-content-scroll">
            <!--Enables this element to be scrolled -->
            <div class="page-fullscreen vertical-bg-3">
                <div class="page-fullscreen-content">
                    <div class="pageapp-login">

                        <div class="pageapp-login-input  animate-fade">
                            <i class="login-icon ion-person"></i>
                            <input id="username" type="email" value="Username" onfocus="if (this.value=='Username') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Username'">
                        </div>
                        <div class="pageapp-login-input  animate-fade animate-delay-100">
                            <i class="login-icon ion-asterisk"></i>
                            <input id="password" type="password" value="Password" onfocus="if (this.value=='Password') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Password'">
                        </div>
                        <div class="pageapp-login-links">
                            <!-- <a href="#" class="page-login-forgot"><i class="ion-ios-eye"></i>Forgot Credentials</a> -->
                            <a href="page-register.html" target="_self" class="page-login-create animate-right">Create Account<i class="ion-person"></i></a>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <button id="btnSubmit" class="button button-green button-icon button-full half-top full-bottom  animate-zoom"><i class="ion-ios-arrow-thin-right"></i>Login</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay dark-overlay"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {

                    }).on('deviceready', function () {
                        document.addEventListener("deviceready", 
 checkExistingSession, false);
                    });
```

js code will load on device ready event and redirect to another page

```
  function checkExistingSession() {

                        var userName = localStorage.getItem("username");
                        var password = localStorage.getItem("password");
                        var deviceType = localStorage.getItem("deviceType");
                        var deviceToken = localStorage.getItem("deviceToken");

                        var parameter = {
                            "username": userName,
                            "password": password,
                            "deviceType": deviceType,
                            "deviceToken": deviceToken
                        }

                        if (userName != null && password != null) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: api_baseUrl + 'login',
                                type: "post",
                                data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (response) {
                                    // Inserting html into the result div on success

                                    if (response !== null && response.status === 1) {
                                        window.location = "dashboard.html";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        window.location = "index.html";
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }

   </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: Are you focusing on the input element when the app loads ??? just to check add "readonly" attribute to your input element just to find issue for now. <input id="username" type="email" value="Username" onfocus="if (this.value=='Username') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Username'" readonly>

Comment: Thanks for you reply..actually i'm not focusing on input element when app loads and tried to add readonly attribute as you suggested but that didn't helped :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [keyboard plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keyboard).

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-keyboard
```

Now on device ready event hide the keyboard.

```
Keyboard.hide();
```

**Edit 1 :-**

try adding this line in androidmanifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: that didn't helped :(

Comment: need more code rather than html. i need to look at the js code as well. code which run when application is launched.

Comment: have you done any change in androidmanifest.xml ??? regarding android:windowSoftInputMode ???

Comment: nope, what should i add in androidmanifest file for hiding keyboard ?

Comment: try to add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" in android manifest but didn't help :(

Comment: Hi @anuj,
I've added js code(edited question) there in my question please have a look into it.

Comment: I've added android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
to androidmanifest and config file as well and it works :)

Comment: if it helped marks it as an answer so it can help others thanks